# Germany GmbH shareholder living in another EU country

Tags: international, tax-law, germany, corporate-tax-laws

When an EU citizen who is holding shares of a GmbH decides to move to another EU country, what are his obligations to the tax office and the state?

Comment: Since GmbH is a German word, I won't ask that it be spelled out, but for the benefit of readers unfamiliar with them, this German abbreviation refers basically to closely held limited liability companies formed under German law that are taxed as corporations. EU of course, refers to the European Union (an international organization that includes Germany as a member).

Answer (score 2):

Germany imposes both entity level (flat 15%) and owner level taxes on a GmbH. But, absent efforts to evade taxes with in kind distributions, the owner level tax is only imposed on distributions which would be called "dividends" in a corporation. A GmbH is not a passthrough taxation entity, unlike partnerships in German tax law.

Distributions to German GmbH owners are subject to a withholding tax that matches Germany's maximum tax rate (which is the normal tax rate) on the distributions, and the owner gets a certificate showing that the withholding tax was paid on the distribution. Since all tax on the distribution that can be owed to Germany by a German GmbH owner is withheld, this income doesn't have to be reported and not further tax payments need to be made in connection with GmbH distributions to German GmbH owners.

A German GmbH owner can, however, declare the income on their income tax return and take a tax credit equal to the tax withheld as shown on the certificate that the German GmbH owner received with the distribution. Sometimes a German GmbH owner can receive special tax benefits thus allowing the owner to receive a partial refund of the tax withheld by the GmbH from their distributions. Usually, this is done by a low income GmbH owner who as a result is subject to a low tax rate on the GmbH owner's personal income.

In the case of a non-German GmbH owner, the same amount of taxes are still withheld from the GmbH distributions to its owners that would be called dividends if it was a corporation, and the owner still gets a certificate showing the amount of withholding tax was that was paid.

But this certificate of tax payment can be used as a credit against the income taxes the non-German GmbH owner owes to the country where the owner resides, instead of against German taxes as they would be for a German GmbH owner. In those situations, the country where the owner lives settles up with Germany to get the withheld taxes that it gave its resident GmbH owner credit for against its taxes under the tax treaties between the two countries. If the income tax rates in the country where the non-German GmbH owner lives are lower than the rate at which German taxes were withheld from the distribution, doing this makes sense.

I do not know if the non-German GmbH owner can elect to not report this income on their income tax return for the country where they reside. I suspect that the answer is "no" but I am unable to confirm that and this could vary from one country to another.

I am not aware of any requirement for the GmbH to provide information tax returns to the tax authorities countries where its owners reside, rather than merely reporting the taxes withheld to Germany, and I suspect that the GmbH is not required to do that. Other countries in the EU can ask Germany's tax officials to provide them with tax information about people in their country, so there is real tax liability risk for a non-German GmbH owner if that owner does not report the distributions that they received from a German GmbH, even if the tax rate in the country of origin is the same or higher than the German GmbH distribution withholding tax rate.

From the perspective of the GmbH, there is basically no difference. The difference in treatment between German GmbH owners and non-German GmbH owners takes place at the level of the individual non-German income tax returns filed by non-German GmbH owners.

> If the profit of a limited liability company is passed on to natural
> persons, the latter is in principle obliged to withhold a capital
> gains tax of 25% (plus 5.5% solidarity surcharge) on this amount and
> to pay it to the tax office. This tax deduction is made for the
> account of the recipient (e.g. shareholder) and does not burden the
> GmbH; only the remaining net amount is paid to the shareholder. The
> limited liability company issues the shareholder with a tax
> certificate according to the model.
>
> This tax deduction generally compensates the shareholder for the
> income tax burden, the so-called final withholding tax. If necessary,
> however, the shareholder can apply for taxation at his individual and
> thus possibly also low income tax rate. In this case, the capital
> gains tax is offset against his income tax.
>
> Special regulations apply to capital gains tax for foreign
> shareholders. In Germany, the profit distributed is subject to a kind
> of withholding tax, which is offset against the corresponding tax of
> the other state. The provisions of the relevant double taxation
> agreements must be observed.

([Source](https://www.liesegang-partner.com/knowhow/corporate-law/taxation-of-a-gmbh))

**Caveat and a footnote regarding terminology**

This answer is limited to German GmbH owners who are natural persons as opposed to entities.

When I use the terms "German" and "non-German" in this answer, I am referring to the the domicile of the GmbH owner and not to the GmbH owner's citizenship.

Comment: Side note: in addition to the 15 % Körperschaftssteuer (KSt, entity level tax, federal), the GmbH pays Gewerbesteuer (GewSt, municipal trade tax; exact height varies by municipality, but order of magnitude is typically similar to KSt)

Comment: +1, very good description of the situation. However, I'd suggest to add that from the point of view of the share holder, there is no difference here whether they own a share in a GmbH or shares of an AG (limited). I.e., the tax procedure is almost exactly the same when they buy some publicly traded (AG) shares via their broker. The only difference is due to those shares not being deposited at the broker, so that they get both the dividend payout and their tax certificate directly from the GmbH.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Good to know on both points. Thanks for the clarification.